# Jquery Qtip2 cannot destroy it

Tags: jquery, qtip2

While using the qtip2 library I have this code:

HTML:

```
<div id="test">Test</div>
<br />
<a id="create">Create</a><br />
<a id="destroy">Destroy</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#create').click(function() {
    $('#test').qtip({content:'test',show: {delay: 0,ready: true,effect: false},hide: false});
});

$('#destroy').click(function() {
   $('#test').qtip('destroy'); 
});
```

If we click on "create" then on "destroy" it work fine, the qtip appears and get destroy.
But if we click twice on "create" then on "destroy", the qtip will not get destroy.

Here a jsfiddle to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/7QmZj/

Anyone have an idea why?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking into possibility of making many qtips? Or you want to limit it to just one? If you do want to make many qtips, when you click destroy, will it destroy all of them?

Comment: There will be multiple qtips on the page, but only one by element.

Comment: In that case the answer by @numbers1311407 will be suitable to your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the existed of the qtip before you create another, something like this before your create:

```
if ($("#test").data("qtip")) return;
```

Comment: Thank you a lots, I fixed my problem with your line. Work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Will there be multiple Qtips on the page for different element ? if not, I have a solution that will remove all qtips from the page, if you double click on Create more than once.

```
    $('#destroy').click(function() 
      {
         $("div[id^=qtip-]").qtip('destroy'); 
      });
```

Just replace your "destroy" bit with mines, Let me know if this works.